# Read hateoas response with embedded HAL collection with spring

Tags: java, spring, client, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to read a REST HATEOAS response like this one :

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"task1"
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/tasks/1"
          },
          "tasks": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/tasks"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/v1/tasks?page=0&size=1"
    }
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 1,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

I'm trying to folloaw the example of spring's documentation : [spring hateoas traverson](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#client.traverson).

Java code :

```java
...
TypeReferences.ResourcesType<Resources<Task>> resourceParameterizedTypeReference = new TypeReferences.ResourcesType<Resources<Task>>(){};

Traverson traverson = new Traverson(new URI("http://localhost:8080/v1/tasks"), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);

Traverson.TraversalBuilder builder = traverson.follow(rel("tasks")).withHeaders(headers);

Resources<Resources<Task>> taskResources = builder.toObject(resourceParameterizedTypeReference);
...
```

But I obtain this error :

```
Did not find LinkDiscoverer supporting media type text/html!
```

Cause : "follow(rel("tasks"))" don't find "tasks".

I'm trying other solutions like this one :
[Deserialize JSON containing (_links and _embedded) using spring-hateoas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813797/deserialize-json-containing-links-and-embedded-using-spring-hateoas), I obtain the error "Expected to find link with rel ..." too.

Maybe finaly I'm not understand the good manner to use traverson object.

I solve my problem by parsing myself the response in Json, but are they another way to get the list contains in the "_embedded" tags in a list of beans ?

If you have some examples I'm interesting :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a Json Path expression to access the embedded content.

```
Traverson.TraversalBuilder builder = traverson.follow("$._embedded.tasks[0]").withHeaders(headers);

Resources<Resources<Task>> taskResources = builder.toObject(resourceParameterizedTypeReference);
```

The following tool is useful for playing with the path expression: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/

BTW, your JSON is missing a "," after the "name".

Comment: ok I've forgotten that you could "navigate" by an expression.
Thanks for the link.